# Child window not closing

Tags: javascript, html

So we have one bug that is affecting mobile devices only and only occurs when the following happens: When you click on a link that opens up a new window (in mobile) if your browser intercepts it with a message like, "pop up blocked.. Do you want to allow `popups`?"

Then when you click "yes" it pops up with the new window, but in that window we have a button that calls `top.window.close()`, and a function:

```
function refreshParent()
{   
    if(!window.opener != null)
    {
        window.opener.location.replace(window.opener.location.href);
    }   

}
```

`refreshParent` is supposed to be called onunload but it doesn't even get called under the previously mentioned circumstances.

Comment: Remove `!` before the `window`. So your condition will be `if(window.opener != null){....`

Comment: @NimittShah That is a good catch but my problem still exists. When the browser asks you if you want to open up the new window it breaks the parent - child relationship (I think) so I can't use top.window.close() because it actually doesn't close anything!